# Why are Python 3 Line breaks \n not working with print and subprocess Popen stdout?

Tags: python-3.x, printing, grep, line-breaks, carriage-return

Python 3.7.1: Calling `grep` with subprocess.Popen to pull errors from a log file. When printing to screen, line breaks \n are not processed.

**Example**

```
a = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "ERR", "errors.log"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(a.stdout.read())
```

**Output**

```
ERR 1 ret: 31113\nERR 2 ret: 35523\nERR 3 ret: 3810 (etc.)
```

Can't imagine why the line breaks are not processed. I would expect this:

```
ERR 1 ret: 31113
ERR 2 ret: 35523
ERR 3 ret: 3810
(etc.)
```

Been combing the 'net for answers, but no luck. Thx :^)

References:

[How would I specify a new line in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497376/how-would-i-specify-a-new-line-in-python)
[Python Popen grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976781/python-popen-grep)

Comment: I think it is due to the newlines, in my case, changing `subprocess.Popen(["grep", "ERR", "errors.log"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` to `subprocess.Popen(["grep", "ERR", "errors.log"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)` worked.

Answer (score 3):

Specify an encoding to decode the subprocess output with.  I can't tell you what your `errors.log` file is encoded with, but give "utf-8" a try:

```
a = Popen(["grep", "ERR", "errors.log"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

`Popen` standard output and errors are *bytes* per default. Printing bytes doesn't try to print the linefeeds as such, but prints their representation instead.

Prior to 3.5, you cannot use `encoding`, but you can certainly decode the output to string using `bytes.decode`:

```
a = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "ERR", "errors.log"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(a.stdout.read().decode())
```

(`decode` can need an argument depending on the contents of the file)